# Edit a rollback's edit reason?

Tags: support, editing

I [rolled back an edit](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/posts/85055/revisions) that a user made to another's code.

It may not be immediately apparent to the most casual observer [*why* I rolled back this edit](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/84943/duplicate-switch-case/85055#comment208761_85055), but the summary just says

> Rollback to revision *N*

To change it, I clicked [*edit*](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/posts/85055/edit/36e9ef04-38bf-4eb9-9b74-22f1e740a987), to make it to the effect of "please don't edit others' code", but upon clicking `Save edits` the edit reason did not update, even though the post changed to say `edited 1 minute ago by cat`.

Can I change a rollback's edit reason, and if so, how?

Comment: I'm not certain, but I believe you did this correctly: you should roll back and then leave a comment to the editor. I don't think many users who don't know not to edit code will look at edit histories, so I think this only will be a problem with other SE vets who don't know about this particular quirk. I don't think that's enough of a problem to warrant a change.

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman So the answer is, "no, you can't edit the reason after the fact, just leave a comment"?

Comment: It's just a guess, if I knew for sure I would have answered :P The rest of my comment was more directed at a potential follow-up, rather than this question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Only moderators can edit revision history comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/59597/180276), including the comment for a rollback.

If you'd like to rollback with a custom comment, go into the revision history of the post and use the *edit* link on a specific revision:

[image: revision history with edit links]

This will bring you to the standard edit page (in which you can enter a custom comment), but containing the contents of the revision you chose instead of the current revision—so if you make no further changes, you are effectively performing a rollback.

If you've already made an edit and you want to add an important piece of information, you can do so in the comments. You may want to leave the message both in the revision history and as a comment if you think it's important that the user whose post you're editing sees your comment.

(As an aside, the moderator revision history editing tool is meant mostly for redacting offensive or sensitive information. You can use a custom moderator flag in that case, but for this situation, it'd be better to just leave a comment.)

Comment: Thanks! As an aside, what do you use for dark mode? :P

Comment: @cat It's a [userstyle I wrote](https://github.com/KeyboardFire/dotfiles/blob/master/.styles/stackexchange.scss) (still WIP, but fairly comprehensive). (Whoops, I forgot it would show up in the screenshot. :P)